# Flutter tab views build method runs even after navigation

Tags: flutter, navigator

I have the following screens

Main Tabs Screen with multiple tabs.
one tab is for listing products.
On listing product screen i use navigator push to open `product detail screen`

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ProductDetails(
            chatItems: mitem,
            currentUserId: widget.currrentUserId,
            groupChatId: mitem.groupChatId,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```

on product detail screen and when `setState` is called
i can see that `main tab screen` build method is also running.
When i am navigated completey it should not run the build method